# How do I switch to updating a bpm diagram created in redhat business management UI to a new tool

Tags: jbpm, redhat-bpm

I've been working on a project which uses the Redhat PAM. The issue is that the diagrams were historically created in Redhat's business intelligence studio (pre 7.0) and since upgrading, this tool is not available in the image and we were advised to use the plugin available for Visual Studio Code.

The issue is that when changing anything in the diagram, it introduces breaking changes. Process variables vanish from the input variable list. Duplicate key errors are reporting on the "problems" tab within the UI.

Other examples of errors are:

19:48:29  [main] ERROR org.drools.core.xml.ExtensibleXmlParser - Node Info: id:_1343724718 name:addException
19:48:29  Parser message: (null: 45, 55): cvc-id.2: There are multiple occurrences of ID value '_1343724718'.

19:48:29  Parser message: (null: 45, 55): cvc-attribute.3: The value '_1343724718' of attribute 'id' on element 'bpmn2:signal' is not valid with respect to its type, 'ID'.
19:48:29  [main] ERROR org.drools.core.xml.ExtensibleXmlParser - Process Info: id:ExceptionHandler, pkg:com.demo.process.model.exception, name:Exception Handler, version:1.0

19:48:59  Node Info: id: name:
19:48:59  Parser message: (null: 1,046, 24): Ignoring  element:  elements should not be used on start or other catch events.
19:48:59  [main] ERROR org.drools.core.xml.ExtensibleXmlParser - Process Info: id:WorkProcessing, pkg:com.demo.process.model.work, name:Work Processing, version:1.0

Has anyone ran into these problems before?